# From which media does this redhead in lingerie painted on a car come?

Tags: itasha

I'm looking for the name of this girl... Does anyone know who she is?

> [image: Source from Timscribbles.com]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This girl is from the [eroge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eroge) Platinum Wind ~Hoshi no Uta ga Kikoetara~

**Description :**

> Albeit tiny, the kingdom of Quartet is prosperous thanks to a mysterious magical light (known as "Platina") that envelops the region. In this bustling city, an alchemist returns home after his apprenticeship.

Here is the original image (/!\ [Not Safe For Work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work) /!\ )

> [image: Platinum Wind]